# I don't want my contacts/friends being shown as suggested contacts. Are these right settings?

Tags: skype, privacy, contacts

I don't want my contacts/friends being shown as suggested contacts and I want people can find me using my Skype ID. So, I turned off "Appear as suggested contacts" and turned on "Appear in search results" (as in the picture attached below). Am I doing it right ?

[image]

Comment: This is the Skype screen from an Android phone.

Comment: Yes, it's from Android Skype.